# Converting a binary string to binary

Tags: c#

I have two string namely string1 and string2. they contain binary numbers and I want to manipulate them with different kinds of operations.

for example:

```
      string string1 = "1000";
      string string2 = "1011";
```

how can I Add/Subtract string1 and string2 so that:

```
      AnswerToAddtion = 10011               //1000 + 1011
      AnswerToSubtratction = 1101           //1000-1011
```

Comment: Try converting them to bytes

Comment: Same solution as: [convert a binary string-representation to a byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436398/convert-a-binary-string-representation-to-a-byte-array)

Comment: Do you want the result of addition/subtraction in a string?

Comment: 1000 - 1011 does not equal 1101.

Comment: This seems to be close to what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/2252904/930878

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Convert.ToInt32("11011",2);` to parse your string to an integer value.

To convert an integer to a binary string, you can use `Convert.ToString(myInt, 2);`

Comment: @ChristopherRayl do you want the result of addition/subtraction in a string? The OP states they want to manipulate the values with different operations, and the problem is the data type is string. I think the solution is to use a more suiting data type.

Comment: I think he just wants to convert a binary string into a binary number so that he can perform binary arithmetic on it.

Comment: @ChristopherRayl what difference should it make to do binary operations on an int32? What data type is a binary type? Int32 should be sufficient. If a binary string result is desired, generating the string is simple enough.

Comment: I think (s)he's looking for something like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2252904/930878